# How to apply a function to each columns in kdb?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have the following,

```
q)add2:{[x]:x+2};
q)Bidcols:`Bid1px`Bid2px`Bid3px;
q)table:([]time:9 11;Bid1px:4 5;Bid2px:7 3;Bid3px:6 8);
time Bid1px Bid2px Bid3px
-------------------------
9    4      7      6
11   5      3      8
```

and I want to apply this add2 function to each cols of the table like the below

```
q)table:update Bid1px:add2'[Bid1px],Bid2px:add2'[Bid2px],Bid3px:add2'[Bid3px] from table;
time Bid1px Bid2px Bid3px
-------------------------
9    6      9      8
11   7      5      10
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to do this using Bidcols?
2. What are the other efficient ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As my answer to your previous question suggested (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68919735/3895697), whenever you want to parameterise a select statement you should consider switching to the functional form.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a function select:

```
q)?[table; (); 0b; `time`Bid1px ! (`time; (each; add2; `Bid1px))]
time Bid1px
-----------
9    6     
11   7
```

For (1), if you want to do it using `Bidcols`:

```
q)?[table; (); 0b; ] (cols table) ! {$[x in Bidcols; (each; add2; x); x]} each cols table
time Bid1px Bid2px Bid3px
-------------------------
9    6      9      8     
11   7      5      10
```

I'm not sure what you mean for (2)? Are you asking for the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: yes, are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Functional select/update are most general and flexible approaches. However, in this particular case reassignment  works well:

```
table[Bidcols]: add2 table[Bidcols];
```

because `add2` function already supports vectors.

If `add` didn't support vectors straightaway, e.g.

```
add: {[x]: $[x>10;x+2;x+3]}
```

Following reassignment would work:

```
table[Bidcols]: (add'') table[Bidcols];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
q)@[table;Bidcols;add2]
time Bid1px Bid2px Bid3px
-------------------------
9    6      9      8
11   7      5      10
```

or

```
q)@[`table;Bidcols;add2]
```

for an in-place update.